# An example for $a^m+a^n= a^{mn}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider **a**  as a **Real nonzero** number, also **m,n**  as two **Natural** numbers.
Could you help me find an example where the equation  $a^m+a^n= a^{mn}$ stands?

Comment: $m=n=2$ and $a=\sqrt2$, that is, $2+2=4$.

Comment: $m = n = 2$ and $a = -\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we can assume $1\le m\le n$.  For $m=1$, the equation $a+a^n=a^n$ has only $a=0$ as a solution.  If $2\le m\le n$, then the polynomial $P(a)=(a^{(n-1)m}-a^{n-m}-1)$ has a positive root $a$, since $P(0)\lt0$ and $P(2)\gt0$.  The latter inequality holds because

$$2^mP(2)=2^{mn}-2^n-2^m\ge2^{2n}-2^n-2^n=2^n(2^n-2)\gt0\quad\text{for }n\gt1$$

It follows that $a^m+a^n=a^{mn}$ always has at least one nonzero solution when $1\lt m,n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one: $a=\sqrt 2$, $m=n=2$.

For $m,n$ both odd, we get a polynomial equation of odd degree and so always has a real root.

For $m$ odd and $n<m$ even, the equation $a^{m(n-1)}=a^{m-n}+1$ has odd degree and so always has a real root, which is not zero.

Comment: For $m,n$ odd, the real root may be $0$, just like for every other case.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė, not the root of $a^{m(n-1)}=a^{m-n}+1$.

Comment: For m,n both odd, m(n-1) is even, so you can't use the "odd degree" argument on the reduced polynomial, only on the original. And we already know that the original has a real root, namely 0, so your argument on the second line doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Qualitatively $ e^x \,+ e^y =  e ^ {x y} $ can be considered for comparison, setting aside large log scaling, It should behave like $ x + y = x \, y $ which is like the hyperbolic lens equation in optics

$$ \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y} = 1 $$

where  $x,y$ are object and image distances for unit focal length.